# Rally: Java: I have few test folders inside a test folder and all folders have test cases. How to get all the test cases using java api

Tags: java, rally

In a rally project, I have the test folder structure as below

```
TestFolderParent1
    testcase1, testcase2..... testcase5
    TestFolderChild1
          testcase10, testcase11..... testcase15     
    TestFolderChild2
          testcase20, testcase21..... testcase25
```

Am using java api to filter as below:

```
QueryRequest testSetRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCases");
testSetRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(new String[] { "Name","FormattedID"}));
testSetRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("TestFolder.Name", "=", "TestFolderParent1"));
```

If I print all the test cases from the response.. it gives only 
testcase1, testcase2..... testcase5

How to get all the test cases which are under subfolders of TestFolderParent1 also.

Thanks,
Venkatesh

Comment: @rachil-hilan @kyle-morse I tried both suggestions. they work fine for my question.But if I have structure like this `<grandparent><parent1><child1><grandchild1>Test cases here</grandchild1><child1><parent1><grandparent>`  it return 0 test cases.. seems it returns the direct test cases to either grand parent folder or parent folder.. But not deeper test folders. any help on this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could add another clause to your query to account for the grandparent case:

```
QueryFilter children = new QueryFilter("TestFolder.Name", "=", "TestFolderParent1");
QueryFilter grandChildren = new QueryFilter("TestFolder.Parent.Name", "=", "TestFolderParent1");
testSetRequest.setQueryFilter(children.Or(grandChildren));
```

This gets clumsy pretty quickly if you have a super deep hierarchy of test folders but should work alright for the case you have mentioned...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good enough but slight modification will fetch your required results. `TestFolder.Parent.Name` will fetch you all test cases from that particular folder irrespective of number of child folders.

```
QueryRequest testSetRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCases");
testSetRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(new String[] { "Name","FormattedID"}));
testSetRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("TestFolder.Parent.Name", "=", "TestFolderParent1"));
```