# How to get whole tree of TestFolders in Rally Rest toolkit for Java ?

Tags: java, tree, rally

In my Rally project I have such testfolder structure:

```
TestFolderGrandGrandParent1
        TestFolderGrandParent1
                 TestFolderParent1
                      testcase1, testcase2..... testcase5
                      TestFolderChild1
                          testcase10, testcase11..... testcase15     
                      TestFolderChild2
                          testcase20, testcase21..... testcase25
                      TestFolderChild3
                          TestFolderGrandChild1
                             testcase20, testcase21..... testcase25
```

I have found ways how to get testcases if I have only 2 level relationship, such as parent, child [(see shared link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37467298/2653036). 
Currently, I am looking for a way to get whole tree, by knowing the very first folder, to get all underlying folders to iterate through each folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no efficient way to do this.  You'll have to query for top level test folders and then recursively traverse the tree, fetching children at each level.

Answer (score 1):

Search for TestFolders in a project. It will list all the test folders in that project.

```
 RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally.rallydev.com/"), "_apogjlfdkjglfjlksr23rfdlj");
    String wsapiVersion = "v2.0";
    String workspaceRef = "/workspace/01245";
    String projectRef = "/project/6757552";
    if(restApi!=null){
        restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
        QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest("TestFolders");
        queryRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(new String[] { "Name","FormattedID","TestFolder"}));

        queryRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        queryRequest.setProject(projectRef);
        queryRequest.setScopedDown(true);
        queryRequest.setLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        queryRequest.setPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        QueryResponse queryResponse = null;
        JsonArray jsonarr = new JsonArray();
        queryResponse = restApi.query(queryRequest);
        int responseTotalResultsCount = queryResponse.getTotalResultCount();
        jsonarr.addAll(queryResponse.getResults());
        int jsonArrSize = jsonarr.size();

        for (int i=0; i<queryResponse.getResults().size();i++){
            JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = queryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println(testCaseJsonObject.getAsJsonObject().get("FormattedID")+": "+testCaseJsonObject.getAsJsonObject().get("Name"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that if there are no duplicate folders, then what you need to do is set the base folder.

Example:

```
new QueryFilter("Name","=","base folder name").and(new QueryFilter("Parent","=","null"))
```

Then you can get the reference of the parent, and get all the children in results and iterate through it referring to each output with previous parent until you get result as [], which indicate that you are on the base folder and then extract the test cases from it.